# Why does this not work ? $array = explode('？', $str);

Tags: php, regex

I have a Chinese paragraph with periods (otherwise known as "full stops") and question marks. I want to explode the paragraph into and array of sentences. I can't seem to get `preg_split(/。|？|！/, $str)` to work with anything that includes the question mark or exclamation. It ignores the question mark and the exclamation point.

I have tried the following and it works fine:

```
$array = explode('。', $okresult);
```

But the following just returns an array with one index filled with the entire paragraph:

```
$array = explode('？', $okresult);
```

Here is the paragraph I am trying to split. It isn't grammatically correct, I am just using it as a test:

> 公元前5世纪，尼希米担任犹太人的省长，他尽心竭力做上帝喜悦的事!例如，他不怕敌人反对，带头重建耶路撒冷的城墙。他执行上帝的律法，关怀受压迫的人，也致力巩固同胞对上帝的信心。上帝有没有留意他这个忠仆的善行呢？尼希米得到耶和华的悦纳吗？我们看看尼希米记的最后一节经文，就知道答案了。

This doesn't work either: `mb_split('？', $okresult);`

Comment: The `？` is not equal to `?`. Is it because of that?

Comment: And try to escape ? with \, use \?

Comment: `preg_split(/。|？|！/, $str)` should be `preg_split("/。|？|！/", $str)`

Comment: Thank you. I tried `mb_split('\？', $str);` and it doesn't work either. Then I tried `mb_split('\?', $str);` and it worked. This is strange because I definitely typed '？' in the test paragraph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the [`/u` Unicode modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) for [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split). Also it's shorter to use a character class here:

```
preg_split('/[。？！]/u', $str)
```

Comment: Thank you, but that didn't work either. I also tried `preg_split('/[。\？\！]/u', $okresult, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);` and `preg_split('/[。\?\!]/u', $okresult, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);`

Comment: Well, works for me: http://ideone.com/ZM8l0H -- Without the `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flag that is.

Comment: Great! It works for me too like this `preg_split('/[。？！?!]/u', $str);` ! Any idea how to get the PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY flag to work?

Comment: I was confused. What I really need is the PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE
flag. It isn't working. Any idea how to get it to work for this?

Comment: Have no idea why both aren't working in /u mode. But as you want to keep the delimiters (should have said so beforehand!) I'd suggest encoding the character class in an assertion `(?<=[...])` - which will keep the 。？！ at sentence ends.

Comment: can you please be more explicit? how exactly do I include that new stuff (`?<=') into the regex in my preg_split function?